# cakephp 2.x select issue with sql server database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am writing below query after connecting sql server in cakephp 2.x.

```php
$this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.USER_ID' => 1)));
```

This produces following query

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 [User].[USER_ID] AS [User__USER_ID], [User].[USER_NAME] AS [User__USER_NAME]
FROM [ec_user_details] AS [User] 
WHERE [User].[USER_ID] = 1
```

The above query through following error

```sql
SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'ec_user_details'.
```

How can I create the following query by ORM in cakephp

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 [User].[USER_ID] AS [User__USER_ID], [User].[USER_NAME] AS [User__USER_NAME]
FROM [**DB_NAME**].[ec_user_details] AS [User] 
WHERE [User].[USER_ID] = 1
```

Please help

Comment: So, your `ec_user_details` table is in a different database than the rest of your tables?

Comment: No it is in the same database(Default DB Config).

Answer (score 0):

After spending lots of time I found the solutions. Add schema in the db config

public $default = array(

```
'host' => '127.0.0.1',
'login' => 'username',
'password' => 'paasword',
'database' => 'db_name',                 
'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
'persistent' => false,
'prefix' => '',
'encoding'  => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8,
'schema'=>'db_name'
```

);